# Using Windows Forms Locks up PowerShell ISE minutes after script has terminated

Tags: winforms, powershell, powershell-4.0

I have an interesting issue here.  I'm creating a calendar picker for use when we create accounts.  It works fine and is still in progress but I have noticed that when I run the script in powershell ISE, after a few minutes it locks up (I am able to edit and save the code for a few minutes prior to that). There is nothing in the event log. I get a dialog box saying that powershell is non responsive.  Memory usage seems normal as well.  I do not know what is happening.

This occurs no matter how I run Powershell ISE (Run as Administrator, Run as another account, and normal ISE) I am running windows 8.1.

A coworker suggested it may be the apartment model, so I've tried STA and MTA, but the problem occurs either way. It does not happen when the same code is run from the console host.

```psh
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

$objForm = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form 

$objForm.Text = "Select a Date" 
$objForm.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(490,250)
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
        {
            $script:dtmDate=$objCalendar.SelectionStart
            $objForm.Close()
        }
    })

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
        {
            $objForm.Close()
        }
    })

$objCalendar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar 
$objCalendar.Text = "Start"
$objCalendar.ShowTodayCircle = $False
$objCalendar.MaxSelectionCount = 1
$objForm.Controls.Add($objCalendar) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})  
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog() 

if ($dtmDate)
    {
        Write-Host "Date selected: $dtmDate"
    }

$objForm.Dispose()
```

---

In Response to @The Unique Paul Smith

```psh
function Find-CalenderDateTest {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$false
    )]
    [ValidateSet('long','short','powerpoint')]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]
    $DateFormat

)

Begin{
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

$objForm = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form 

$objForm.Text = "Select a Date" 
$objForm.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(243,250) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True

$dtmDate = $null

$objForm.Add_KeyDown( {
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
        {
            $dtmDate=$objCalendar.SelectionStart
            $objForm.Close()
        }
    })


$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
        {
            $objForm.Close()
        }
    })

#region   OK Button
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,175)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"

# Got rid of the Click event for OK Button, and instead just assigned its DialogResult property to OK.
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK

$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

# Setting the form's AcceptButton property causes it to automatically intercept the Enter keystroke and
# treat it as clicking the OK button (without having to write your own KeyDown events).
$objForm.AcceptButton = $OKButton
#endregion 

#region Cancel Button
$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,175)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"

# Got rid of the Click event for Cancel Button, and instead just assigned its DialogResult property to Cancel.
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel

$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

# Setting the form's CancelButton property causes it to automatically intercept the Escape keystroke and
# treat it as clicking the OK button (without having to write your own KeyDown events).
$objForm.CancelButton = $CancelButton
#endregion 

$objCalendar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar 
$objCalendar.ShowTodayCircle = $False
$objCalendar.MaxSelectionCount = 1
$objForm.Controls.Add($objCalendar) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})  

$Results = $objForm.ShowDialog()
}

Process{}

End{
if ($Results -eq "OK")
    {
    $objCalendar.SelectionStart
    }

$objForm.Dispose()

}
}
```

Comment: A few questions: 1. Does it lock up whilst running the calender or does it lock up after you close the "Select a Date" window? 2. Does it do this on the first run or does it happen after being run a few times. 3. Is this 32 bit or 64 bit PowerShell/ISE. More precise steps to repro would be useful.

Comment: I am the coworker in question, so I saw this happen. 1) It happens well after the entire script has stopped executing (the ISE indicates that it's not running anymore). It doesn't happen during execution. 2) I believe it can happen with a single run, but @DJ Torres will have to confirm. 3) 64 bit. As for more precise steps, I believe it's as simple as running the code, then waiting a while. It seemed to take over 10 minutes in some instances.

Comment: 1. Yes happens after script has done executing and after one run
2. Can happen on a single run, or mutiple runs
3. I will let the calender run idle and see if it locks up.

To reproduce:
1. Copy paste code into Powershell ISE (64Bit) in console window or in script pane or console
2. Save code (Optional)
3. Run Code
4. Select Date
5. Press enter after date selected
6. Wait a few minutes and powershell will lock up

Comment: Appreciated.....now waiting....and waiting...... :)

Comment: I just tested on 2012 R2, opened a new ISE window, pasted code, ran it. Then I went to run `Get-Date` in the immediate window so I could time how long it took to lock up, and `Get-Date` never returned. So this one took less than a minute. Did the same in a console host; no issues.

Comment: Ok...tried this on Windows 7 x64 and 2012R2 and I can't repro this.

Comment: Sorry folks, wish I could repro. I was going to capture a process dump then load that up in WinDBG and SOS and have a poke around to see where it was getting stuck.

Comment: My ISE just crashed again this time, I did not run the whole script only copy pasted up until the [void] $objForm.ShowDialog() in the console window of the ISE. is there way I can send you some sort of process dump.  If so Please let me know how before I restart ISE.

Comment: Also adding that I tried this on a Windows 8.1 machine at home, not connected to or configured similarly to any of our company's domain machines. It took over an hour (possibly over 2), but it did eventually lock up.

Comment: This Will not help, but I met exactly the same trouble when I call an external Class written in C# using Forms exposing my dialog boxes. My ISE always froze when I have used the scripts launching these classes, not during the usage, but a few minutes after when ISE was idle. It works as if starting using Windows Forms in ISE consume some ressource. I spent much time on it.

Comment: @JPBlanc how did you resolve the issue?

Comment: At the moment I live with it, launching these script from non ISE PowerShell.

Comment: My first thought is that it's an async deadlock. However, what looks incorrect is the `$objForm.Add_KeyDown`. Since this is Powershell, you should really look into `Register-ObjectEvent`

Answer (score 4):

The error is MTA/STA

Don't use

```
$form.showDialog()
```

Use

```
[system.windows.forms.application]::run($form)
```

instead

and it works fine every time

Another way is to put it in another thread:

```
$code
{
  //form code here
  $form.showDialog()
}
$newThread = [Powershell]::Create()
$newThread.AddScript($code)
$handle = $newThread.BeginInvoke()
```

Provide variables from the calling script:

`$newThread.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("variablenname",value)`

before the `BeginInvoke` use `variablenname` without $...

Comment: Thus, it should be clear to everyone that this is not an issue, but a programming mistake, because ISE is MTA and forms need STA. If you call showDialog() the Parent is the ISE (MTA).

Comment: run($form) works, thank you! Dennis, what do you mean is the correct way to call showDialog() from ISE?

Comment: [system.windows.forms.application]::run($form) did the trick. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It's a long shot but the problem might be that powershell is not closing the $objForm object correctly, leaving it running in memory while the ISE waits for input after the script has terminated. If you check your taskmanager, is the form still running in the background? You could also try adding 'Remove-Variable objForm' (no $) after the dispose() and see if that helps.

More information: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730962.aspx

As I say, it's a long shot.

Comment: 1. The window is in task manager when the dialog is open but disappear when we select the date and press enter
2. I will try to add Remvove-Variable obForm and see if that works

Comment: 1. I ran the remove variable method and ran a loop with get date and it failed in an hour and a half.   It did however crash powershell prompting me to reboot, however the logs from the time I restarted the ISE and when it actally crashed showed no logs in the event log.
2. I ran the code in a different ISE session without the remove variable and failed in 30 minutes with just an ISE Lockup

Comment: We also floated a theory that the inconsistent timing of the crash might indicate that it happens during garbage collection, so we've tried to force it with `[System.GC]::Collect()`, however this appears to have no effect on when the crash occurs.

Comment: When I run that script I notice that the $objForm is never actually disposed. I think this is because it's still attached to the pipeline so it can never really get garbage collected. Try putting the script into a simple function where all the logic is executed as part of the begin{} with the disposing happening at the end{} of the function. More details found here [Powershell & Disposing](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f7cec41e-26a8-4483-bdf8-83eecbfef579/powershell-and-object-disposing)

Comment: So @briantist go the memory dump route to confirm your suspicion. You could provide some more details, like which LoC fails? Have you tried trapping the error?

Comment: @JeremyThompson there is no error to trap. The entire ISE just locks up (does not redraw the window, doesn't accept input, doesn't change mouse cursor, etc.), and this happens well after the PowerShell script is done executing.

Comment: @TheUniquePaulSmith I've edited my question to include my function for others to test with your idea of disposing of the form in the end. I'm running "do{Start-Sleep -Seconds 10;Get-Date}while($aa -eq $null)" and will let update this response when it crashes

Comment: @TheUniquePaulSmith so my ISE Session has not locked up, I'm going to try one more time and make sure this actually solved the problem. Can you please tell me how you noticed the objform was not being disposed of properly?

Comment: @TheUniquePaulSmith I'm not sure what happened over the weekend but the new method locked up ISE again,  I ran the same set of test in multiple computers running multiple instances of ISE: 1) Ran just the script 2)As a function 3) As a function with with the End Process disposing

Comment: @DJTorres, i'm starting to suspect that it's related to your ISE application and not the script / logic itself since it doesn't happen in a regular powershell console.. Can you verify this by seeing if the ISE locks up for any other completely unrelated script? Can you check to ensure there are no "Add-Ons" loaded in the ISE that is causing it to be problematic?

Comment: @TheUniquePaulSmith I'm actually using ISE Now. Got busy so I had to put away the code for a bit,  ISE has not locked up and I am running about 5 instances of ISE with various scripts and a few for testing some code that has no add ons.

Comment: @TheUniquePaulSmith we have tried this on many machines, it's not just his specific ISE. We don't use any add-ons, but it's always ISE that's affected and not the console. We use ISE constantly for other scripts, and it never locks up with those. JPBlanc seems to have had a similar problem (see the comments on the question) but was unable to solve it.

Comment: I've been seeing what I think is the same issue. I code/debug/test a particular Winforms based script many times during the day and evening. ISE works fine the whole time. But usually the next day ISE is locked up.  I'm pretty sure my script is completely unrelated :-).

Answer (score 1):

I was using `combobox.items.add`:

```
$configCombo.Items.Add($wks)
```

and I looked up how to keep the keys from printing to the console - and changed the add to:

```
[void]$configCombo.Items.Add($wks)
```

Since then I have added the void - I have been running it in ISE and it has not hung since.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue too. Generally occurs when I lock my workstation and return. After a bit of poking about and googleing, I found this
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943139/windows-forms-application-freezes-when-system-settings-are-changed-or, which seems like the issue at hand.

**Issue**

> The application will not respond and the UI thread will hang in an
>   Invoke call while handling the OnUserPreferenceChanged notification

**Cause**

> This occurs if a control is created on a thread which doesn't pump
>   messages and the UI thread receives a WM_SETTINGCHANGE message.

**Resolution**

> Applications should never leave Control objects on threads without an
>   active message pump. If Controls cannot be created on the main UI
>   thread, they should be created on a dedicated secondary UI thread and
>   Disposed as soon as they are no longer needed.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, but the solution is: Always clean up right after the form is done.
In this case:

```
$objForm.Dispose()
```

Up to now (a few hours) I didn't have that issue again. Previously it locked up after > 10 Minutes.