# How can I escape a read-host by pressing escape?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

just wondering if its possible to escape a read-host in a while loop by pressing escape.

I've tried doing an do-else loop but it will only recognize button presses outside of the read-host.

This is basically what I have

```
#Import Active Directory Module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#Get standard variables
$_Date=Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"
$_Server=Read-Host "Enter the domain you want to search"

#Request credentials
$_Creds=Get-Credential

while($true){

    #Requests user input username
    $_Name=Read-Host "Enter account name you wish to disable"

    #rest of code
    }
```

I want to be able to escape it if I want to change the domain

Comment: you can't do that with `Read-Host`. [*grin*] it REQUIRES an "enter" or break to end input, so you are stuck if you must use that cmdlet. if you want to allow that way out, then you will need to wrap the console readkey method to read one-keypress-at-a-time - not my idea of fun. [*grin*]

Comment: Ah okay, it wasn't really a necessary thing for the script, would've just made it a tad nicer. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Enter a blank account name, and have `if ("" -eq $_Name) { break }` after that line? Or press Ctrl-C ?

Comment: @Davkro - add an option on your user prompt that says something like "select 'x' to exit ..." ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

Using `Read-Host` you cannot do this, but you might consider using a graphical input dialog instead of prompting in the console. After all, the `Get-Credential` cmdlet also displays a GUI.

If that is an option for you, it can be done using something like this:

```
function Show-InputBox {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$Message, 

        [string]$Title = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($MyInvocation.PSCommandPath),

        [string]$defaultText = ''
    )
    Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.VisualBasic'
    return [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($Message, $Title, $defaultText)
}

while($true) {
    $_Name = Show-InputBox "Enter account name you wish to disable"
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_Name)) {
        # the box was cancelled, so exit the loop
        break
    }
    # proceed with the rest of the code
}
```

If the user presses the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, clicks <kbd>Cancel</kbd>, or leaves the input blank, you can exit the while loop, otherwise proceed with the code.

Comment: When using Winforms or VisualBasic from ISE, beware [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808084/using-windows-forms-locks-up-powershell-ise-minutes-after-script-has-terminated) issue. It hasn't stopped me from using InputBox, but it's annoying.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with `Read-Host`, but you can do it via the [`PSReadLine` module](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine) (ships with Windows PowerShell version 5 or higher on Windows 10 / Windows Server 2016) and PowerShell Core) and its `PSConsoleHostReadline` function:

**Important:**

- **As of PSReadLine v2.2.6, the solution below is a *hack***, because the `PSConsoleHostReadline` only supports prompting for *PowerShell statements*, not open-ended user input.

  - **[GitHub issue #881](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/881) proposes that the function be optionally usable for *general-purpose* user input as well**, which would allow for a greatly customizable end-user prompting experience. Make your voice heard there, if you'd like see this suggestion implemented.
- **The hack should work in *your* case**, since the usernames you're prompting for should be syntactically valid PowerShell statements.

  - However, **supporting arbitrary input is problematic for two reasons**:

    - Inapplicable syntax coloring will be applied - you could, however, temporarily set all configurable colors to the same color, but that would be cumbersome.
    - More importantly, if an input happens to be something that amounts to a syntactically *incomplete* PowerShell statement, `PSConsoleHostReadline` won't accept the input and instead continue to prompt (on a new line); for instance, input `a|` would cause this problem.
- Also:

  - Whatever input is submitted is invariably added to the *command history*.
  - While you can currently *remove* a temporarily installed keyboard handler on exiting a script, there is no robust way to *restore a previously active one* - see [GitHub issue #880](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/880).

```bash
 # Set up a key handler that cancels the prompt on pressing ESC (as Ctrl-C would).
 Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key Escape -Function CancelLine

 try {

   # Prompt the user:
   Write-Host -NoNewline 'Enter account name you wish to disable: '
   $_Name = PSConsoleHostReadLine

   # If ESC was pressed, $_Name will contain the empty string.
   # Note that you won't be able to distinguish that from the user
   # just pressing ENTER.
   $canceled = $_Name -eq ''

   # ... act on potential cancellation 

 } finally {

   # Remove the custom Escape key handler.
   Remove-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key Escape

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function that works for me.

```
# Returns the string "x" when Escape key is pressed, or whatever is indicated with -CancelString
# Pass -MaxLen n to define max string length
function Read-HostPlus()   
{
    param 
    ( 
        $CancelString = "x",    
        $MaxLen = 60            
    )     
    $result = ""
    $cursor = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates
    while ($true)
    {
        While (!$host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable ){}
        $key = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho, IncludeKeyDown")
        
        switch ($key.virtualkeycode) 
        {
            27 { While (!$host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable ){}; return $CancelString }
            13 { While (!$host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable ){}; return $result }   
            8  
            {
                if ($result.length -gt 0)
                {
                    $cursor = $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition                    
                    $width = $host.UI.RawUI.MaxWindowSize.Width
                    if ( $cursor.x -gt 0) {  $cursor.x--  }
                    else {  $cursor.x = $width -1; $cursor.y--  }
                    $Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $cursor  ;   write-host " "  ;  $Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $cursor
                    $result = $result.substring(0,$result.length - 1 )                  
                }
            }            
            Default 
            {
                $key_char = $key.character  
                if(  [byte][char]$key_char -ne 0  -and  [byte][char]$key_char -gt 31 -and ($result + $key_char).Length -le $MaxLen  )
                {                                      
                    $result += $key_char 
                    $cursor.x = $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition.X                              
                    Write-Host $key_char -NoNewline
                    if ($cursor.X -eq $host.UI.RawUI.MaxWindowSize.Width-1 ) {write-host " `b" -NoNewline }    
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```